# Error while doing escape interpolation inside assert_select in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a project which is currently in rails-4.2.10 and
I want to do something like this:

```
assert_select ".note-nid-#{node.id}", false
```

But while testing it errors pops up:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)
```

while if I try:

```
assert_select '.note-nid-#{node.id}', false
```

no error pops up.
So basically how do I do escape interpolation inside assert_select in rails 4.2

Comment: Could you show the full trace of the error?

Comment: Error:
Minitest::Result#test_first-timer_moderated_note_(status=4)_hidden_to_normal    _users_on_research_note_feed:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)
test/functional/notes_controller_test.rb:239:in `block in <class:NotesControllerTest>'

Comment: this is the full error

Comment: And line 239 of your test/functional/notes_controller_test.rb is the assert_select you describe in your question?

Comment: Yeah line 239 is the same assert_select

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this problem. We can do it by

`selector = css_select ".note-nid-#{node.id}"`

`assert_equal selector.size, 0`